# Why do gdal_warp and gdal_translate only offer polynomial/thin plate spline transformation?

Tags: python, transform, gis, raster, gdal

I need to georeference several images with shared ground control points, for which I wrote a script in python that uses gdal_translate to properly reference the images. My issue is however that the gdal_translate distorts the x:y ratio of the image by scaling both individually. I would have expected there to be an option to perform a linear/4 degrees of freedom (x and y shift, rotation and a single scaling) affine transformation on the images, however this does not seem to be the case?

I am currently using the following command:

```sh
gdal_translate -of GTIFF -a_srs "EPSG:27700" points.points in.tiff out.tiff
```

points.points are my GCPs.

From the gdal_warp documentation, it seems that the default behaviour is to use polynomial transformation based on the number of GCPs, with an option to force TPS:

> -order n
>
> order of polynomial used for warping (1 to 3). The default is to select a polynomial order based on the number of GCPs.
>
> -tcp
>
> Force use of thin plate spline transformer based on available GCPs.

**EDIT**: Changed question title and body a little to better reflect what I am looking for